# Covariance between number of times 1 and 2 appear in n rolls of a k sided die

Tags: probability, dice, covariance

Consider n independent tosses of a k-sided fair die. Let $X_i$ be the number of tosses that result in i. What would be the covariance between $X_1$ and $X_2$ ?

I can't seem to get my head around this problem.
I know that

$Cov(X_1,X_2) = E[X_1 X_2] - E[X_1]E[X_2]$.

I believe $P(X_1) = {{N}\choose{X_1}} * (1/k)^{X_1} * (k-1/k)^{n-X_1} $
and $E[X_1] = \sum_{i=0}^{n} X_1 * P(X_1)$

but I can't take it from here any further. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you familiar with the technique of using Indicator Random Variables to simplify covariance of counts of events among sequences of trials?

Begin like this:-

Let $Y_k$ be the indicator random variable that roll $k$ is a `1`, and $Z_k$ be that for being a `2`.

So $X_1=\sum_{k=1}^n Y_k\;, X_2=\sum_{j=1}^n Z_j$

By the Bilinarity of Covariance:

$$\mathsf {Cov}(X_1,X_2) = \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n\mathsf {Cov}(Y_k,Z_j) $$

Because these are Indicator Random Variables,

$$\begin{align}\mathsf{Cov}(Y_k,Z_j) &= \mathsf P(Y_k=1,Z_j=1)-\mathsf P(Y_k=1)\mathsf P(Z_j=1) \\[1ex]&= \mathsf P(Y_k=1, Z_j=1)-\tfrac 1{36}\end{align}$$

Next, you must consider the cases where $k=j$ and where $k\neq j$

$\vdots$

Comment: Got it. Thanks alot